# How do I install one or more versions of MySQL and switch between the versions when I need?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, mysql, php

I have a development machine built on Lubuntu. Now, I have a requirement to test the code on various PHP and MySQL versions. Switching between PHP versions is not a problem. But my main problem is to install different versions of MySQL and switching between them, when I need?

I hope there is a same procedure for Ubuntu also.

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one version of MySQL on the same machine using `apt-get`.

I would install all MySQL versions using docker. They have [instructions](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) on their site.

Docker you can install from apt-get or with ...

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Downloading and setting up 5.5 rerouting port 3306 to 3406:

```
sudo docker run --name MySQL55 -p 127.0.0.1:3406:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD={password} -d mysql:5.5
```

- {password} is used to set the root password; so change this.
- You can use this to create another one for "5.6", "5.7", "latest" etc. The 5.5 at the end is the tag for docker; see the link for more tags. Supported tags:

  ```
  8.0.3, 8.0, 8 (8.0/Dockerfile)
  5.7.21, 5.7, 5, latest (5.7/Dockerfile)
  5.6.39, 5.6 (5.6/Dockerfile)
  5.5.59, 5.5 (5.5/Dockerfile)
  ```

The link has tons of info on how to connect and use different docker containers.

Comment: I just try but is not workable. Do you have some better explanation how to run properly? also docker only can be properly installed via  apt-get install docker.io